# Disabling random ordering on reviewing area should default to Newest First ordering

Tags: feature-request, flags, review

It's really great that we can view review posts by looking at different orderings, including random and non-random. When you turn off random ordering, though, the ordering defaults to most-votes first, or at least it is for me. This is very unlikely to be the ordering that is most useful for finding the posts that need cleaning up: the best new posts (as determined by voting) are shown first, and if you reverse the ordering, you see the ones that other people have already downvoted and/or flagged as spam.

I always end up switching the ordering to "Newest first". In my experience this is the view that turns up the most posts needing flagging, editing or otherwise cleaning up.

I would like to suggest that "Newest first" be the default non-random ordering in the review views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been done with the new functionality and interface for reviewing. I certainly find it more useful, and judging by the reduced amount of rubbish that I actually need to flag and [the greater amount of reviewing activity generally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112600/has-the-new-reviewing-interface-and-or-the-badge-objectively-reduced-spam-and-no) it has been very successful.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a built in solution, but you could create a bookmark to the review page, pre-configured the way you like it.

[Taking the settings from Lance's answer as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&customsort=newestfirst&no-random=1):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?s=1&pagesize=50&filter=day&customsort=newestfirst&no-random=1
```

Comment: Now we just need a GM script to have that replace the code behind the Review link.

Answer (score 1):

That would be nice, right now I have 3 clicks to make every time I go to the review page:

1) At bottom of page, click on `disable random ordering`
2) After refresh, at bottom of page click on `boxed-50` (on SO)
3) After refresh, a little ways down page, click on `Newest first`

What would solve all this clicking is `sticky` settings, but your idea would save one click per review session.

Comment: I got sick of constantly having to scroll to be bottom just to disable random ordering, so I hacked together a userscript to bring the sort options to the top of the page. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113590/134327

Comment: Actually, they fixed this problem and now the settings are sticky.

Comment: Yes, but the stickiness is lost once you enter the suggested-edits tab :(